# How can I put a div to another row?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-float

I have a project like this http://codepen.io/zhangolve/pen/WGvbNv ,I want to put the 'nextrow' div to another row.what should I do?

The code looks like this:

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
  font-size: 12;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class='card'>
    <p><span>TEST</span><span> A </span>
    </p>
    <p><span>TEST</span><span> B</span>
    </p>
    <p><span>TEST</span>  <span> C</span>
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class='card'>
    <p><span>TEST</span><span> A </span>
    </p>
    <p><span>TEST</span><span> B</span>
    </p>
    <p><span>TEST</span>  <span> C</span>
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class='card'>
    <p><span>TEST</span><span> A </span>
    </p>
    <p><span>TEST</span><span> B</span>
    </p>
    <p><span>TEST</span>  <span> C</span>
    </p>

  </div>
</div>
<div id='nestrow'>
  <h2>test </h2>
</div>
```

actually,I have to use react to make it .so both of your answers use preudo-element,but in react ,there is no the style.How can I make the same effect by react?  my react part code like this:

```
  var Message = React.createClass({


     render: function() {  
    var style = {
    card: {
    boxShadow: '0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
    transition: '0.3s',
    width: '30%',
    float:'left',
    margin:'1%',
    fontSize: '12'
        }



    };
    return (

        <div>

        <div>
        <div style={style.card}>
            <p><span>TEST</span><span> A</span></p>
            <p><span>TEST</span><span> B</span></p>
            <p><span>TEST</span><span> C</span></p>

        <div>
        <div   style={style.card}>
            <p><span>TEST</span><span> A</span></p>
            <p><span>TEST</span><span> B</span></p>
            <p><span>TEST</span><span> C</span></p>
        </div>
         <div  style={style.card}>

            <p><span>TEST</span><span> B</span></p>
            <p><span>TEST</span><span> C</span></p>
        </div>

        </div>

        <div>
        <h2>test</h2>

        </div>
        </div>

      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear the `float`s and and that will do!

Added `wrapper` class to your `card`s and applied this style to it:

```
.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Let me know your feedback. Thanks!

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
  font-size: 12;
  color: blue;
}
.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class='card'>
    <p><span>TEST</span><span> A </span>
    </p>
    <p><span>TEST</span><span> B</span>
    </p>
    <p><span>TEST</span>  <span> C</span>
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class='card'>
    <p><span>TEST</span><span> A </span>
    </p>
    <p><span>TEST</span><span> B</span>
    </p>
    <p><span>TEST</span>  <span> C</span>
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class='card'>
    <p><span>TEST</span><span> A </span>
    </p>
    <p><span>TEST</span><span> B</span>
    </p>
    <p><span>TEST</span>  <span> C</span>
    </p>

  </div>
</div>
<div id='nestrow'>
  <h2>test </h2>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2**:

Use this instead of `psuedo` element styling:

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Hope this works for you

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
  font-size: 12;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class='card'>
    <p><span>TEST</span><span> A </span>
    </p>
    <p><span>TEST</span><span> B</span>
    </p>
    <p><span>TEST</span>  <span> C</span>
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class='card'>
    <p><span>TEST</span><span> A </span>
    </p>
    <p><span>TEST</span><span> B</span>
    </p>
    <p><span>TEST</span>  <span> C</span>
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class='card'>
    <p><span>TEST</span><span> A </span>
    </p>
    <p><span>TEST</span><span> B</span>
    </p>
    <p><span>TEST</span>  <span> C</span>
    </p>

  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<div id='nestrow'>
  <h2>test </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry ,I must to say  for  convenience，I descriped the question，but actually I want to achieve the goal by using react,can you help me ?

Comment: anyway,thank you.Finally ,I import a module to the project and the module has ‘’grid systems” component ，so I resolved the problem by the way.

Comment: of course ,I will learn your code and get some new knowledge!  LOL

Comment: cool... could you please upvote  / accept answer if this helped you? Thanks!

Comment: sorry,I just have 14 reputation ,not enough to 15,maybe you can upvote the question and I get 5 reputation and give your answer a upvote.

Comment: @zhangolve could you please mark the answer as correct too so that if anyone visits the question, they know that the issue has been resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
.row{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.card{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  float: left;
}

.card:last-child{
  margin-right: 0;
}

.card span{
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="card">
    <p>
      <span>Test A</span>
      <span>Test B</span>
      <span>Test C</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>
      <span>Test A</span>
      <span>Test B</span>
      <span>Test C</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>
      <span>Test A</span>
      <span>Test B</span>
      <span>Test C</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <h2>Test</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes,your answer is awesome,but ,sorry ,I must to say for convenience，I descriped the question，but actually I want to achieve the goal by using react,can you help me ?I have updated the question.